# Como verificar se dado já existe no banco antes de inserir outro em angular?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, angularjs

Já tenho feita uma modal que recebe um nome, ele manda pro controller na função de inserir novo contato. Quero verificar se esse dado já esta cadastrado no banco para que não o cadastrem novamente. Alguem sabe como posso fazer isso em AngularJS?

Fiz isso até o momento...

```
//Carrega as categorias existentes

 var carregaCategorias = function(){
            var tam = $scope.categoria.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < tam; i++)
                $scope.categorias[i] = $scope.categoria[i].nome;
        }

//Verifica se já está inserido

$scope.createCategory = function(typeOfCategory, modalId){ //OK

            var typeCategory;
            var category = $scope.novaCategoria;

            if(category == ?? )
```

Comment: Quando você vai verificar se já está inserido, você manda o "novo" objeto no método de verificação? Se sim, você poderia fazer um `SELECT COUNT` na tabela com uma clausula de equalidade/LIKE.

Algo como `SELECT COUNT(nome) FROM categoria WHERE nome LIKE %dado_procurado%`, por exemplo. E ai, caso o resultado seja igual a zero, permitir a adição.

Comment: Bom dia! Amigo ou vc cria uma query no banco como citado acima e retorna uma valor indicando se existe ou não um item parecido ou vc faz uma requisição na API trazendo todos os registros e verifica no front se ja tem algum registro similar, porém acredito que uma query fazendo essa verificação seria ideal.

Comment: Acredito que a melhor maneira seria fazer isso na própria hora de inserir e através e somente do seu código backend fazer essa verificação se já existe, caso não exista insira